# Hibernate throws HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

So I have a table that I've defined as an entity in hibernate like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sec_Preference")
public class Preference {
private long id;

@Column(name = "PreferenceId", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private long systemuserid;

@Column(name = "SystemUserId", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public long getSystemUserId() {
    return systemuserid;
}

public void setSystemUserId(long systemuserid) {
    this.systemuserid = systemuserid;
}

private long dbgroupid;

@Column(name = "DBGroupId", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public long getDBGroupId() {
    return dbgroupid;
}

public void setDBGroupId(long dbgroupid) {
    this.dbgroupid = dbgroupid;
}

private long externalgroupid;

@Column(name = "ExternalGroupId", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public long getExternalGroupId() {
    return externalgroupid;
}

public void setExternalGroupId(long externalgroupid) {
    this.externalgroupid = externalgroupid;
}

private long securityroleid;

@Column(name = "SecurityRoleId", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Basic
public long getSecurityRoleId() {
    return securityroleid;
}

public void setSecurityRoleId(long securityroleid) {
    this.securityroleid = securityroleid;
}

public void setEnum(com.vitalimages.common.server.security.Preference pref) {
    this.preferencekey = pref.name();
}

private String preferencekey;

@Column(name = "PreferenceKey", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255, precision = 0)
@Basic
public String getKey() {
    return preferencekey;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.preferencekey = key;
}

private String preferencevalue;

@Column(name = "PreferenceValue", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 255, precision = 0)
@Basic
public String getValue() {
    return preferencevalue;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.preferencevalue = value;
}

}
```

When I tried to write a simple query against this table:

```
public Collection<Preference> getPreferencesForDBGroup(long dbgroupId) {
    final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Preference.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("dbgroupid", dbgroupId))
            .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: dbgroupid of: com.common.server.domain.sec.Preference; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: dbgroupid of: com.common.server.domain.sec.Preference
```

Why can't hibernate figure out what dbgroupid is on my class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's probably because your getter (and setter) is not following the javabeans convention. It should be:

```
public long getDbgroupId() {
    return dbgroupid;
}
```

What I'd suggest is - name your fields, and then use your IDE to generate setters and getters. It will follow the convention. (Another thing, that is a matter of preference, but in my opinion makes a class easier to read - annotate your fields, not getters)

Comment: @Ralph - yes, it is not prohibited. But I took his field name as a starting point, hence I suggested a getter change. It could've been the other way around. But you are right that multiple capital letters in the beginning is tricky.

Comment: You are right - is miss understud your anser - so i remove my comment already

Comment: I had a similar problem where I was using all uppercase and was not finding the right getter: `.add(Restrictions.eq("DBGROUPID", dbgroupId))`

Comment: Instead of letting your IDE generate the getters and setters, better use [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/download.html)

Answer (score 6):

Well I made some progress on this but I still don't understand where hibernate gets its names.  I debugged into the guts of hibernate and found the following class:

```
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping
```

In this class there is a method:

```
public Type toType(String propertyName) throws QueryException {
    Type type = (Type) typesByPropertyPath.get(propertyName);
    if (type == null) {
        throw propertyException(propertyName);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Which tries to resolve the name given in the criteria against the object.  So in the typesByPropertyPath map I found the following values:

```
id -> DBGroupId=org.hibernate.type.LongType@1e96ffd
key -> value=org.hibernate.type.StringType@aa2ee4
value -> value=org.hibernate.type.StringType@aa2ee4
systemUserId -> DBGroupId=org.hibernate.type.LongType@1e96ffd
securityRoleId -> DBGroupId=org.hibernate.type.LongType@1e96ffd
externalGroupId -> DBGroupId=org.hibernate.type.LongType@1e96ffd
DBGroupId -> DBGroupId=org.hibernate.type.LongType@1e96ffd
```

Here you can see that the CAPITALIZATION of DBGroupId did not match what I had in my criteria.  So I changed that from dbgroupid to DBGroupId like this:

```
public Collection<Preference> getPreferencesForDBGroup(long dbgroupId) {
    final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Preference.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("DBGroupId", dbgroupId))
            .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because You've labelled it "DBGroupId", and not "dbgroupid"?

Comment: Is that because I have it declared on the getXXX method?  And that is where it gets the capitalization?