# could not resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, join, detachedcriteria

I have join two table .i want retrieve data by adding some detached criteria but it show "could not resolve property" error.

"userMaster" table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_master")
public class UserMasterTbl implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="E_MAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="CREATE_DTM")
    private Date createDtm;

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID")
    private UserRoleTbl userRole;

    //private
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="created_by", nullable = true)
    private UserMasterTbl createdBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="createdBy")
    private Set<UserMasterTbl> createdUserList = new HashSet<UserMasterTbl>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "createdBy", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<OrderMasterTbl> orders;

    public UserMasterTbl() {
    }

    /*** getter and setter *******/
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setCreateDtm(Date createDtm) {
        this.createDtm = createDtm;
    }

    public Date getCreateDtm() {
        return this.createDtm;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UserMasterTbl other = (UserMasterTbl) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

"userDetailed" table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_detailed")
public class UserDetailedTbl implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "newGenerator") //name of the primary key generator
    @GenericGenerator(name = "newGenerator", strategy = "foreign",parameters = { @Parameter(value = "userMasterTbl", name = "property") })
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="COMPANY_NAME")
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="FAX1_NO")
    private String faxNumber;

    @Column(name="CELL_NUMBER")
    private String cell_number;

    //map with user_master_tabel
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    private UserMasterTbl userMasterTbl; 

    /* getter and setter */

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getFaxNumber() {
        return faxNumber;
    }

    public void setFaxNumber(String faxNumber) {
        this.faxNumber = faxNumber;
    }

    public String getCell_number() {
        return cell_number;
    }

    public void setCell_number(String cell_number) {
        this.cell_number = cell_number;
    }

    public UserMasterTbl getUserMasterTbl() {
        return userMasterTbl;
    }

    public void setUserMasterTbl(UserMasterTbl userMasterTbl) {
        this.userMasterTbl = userMasterTbl;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UserDetailedTbl other = (UserDetailedTbl) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Data accessing criteria:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserDetailedTbl.class);
criteria.add(Expression.in("userMasterTbl.status", userRoles))
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/AddNector] threw exception [Request processing failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: userMasterTbl.status of: com.queenzend.addnector.model.UserDetailedTbl;
nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userMasterTbl.status of: com.queenzend.addnector.model.UserDetailedTbl] with root cause org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userMasterTbl.status of: com.queenzend.addnector.model.UserDetailedTbl
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.throwPropertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toColumns(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1304)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumnsUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.InExpression.toSqlString(InExpression.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1550)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1039)
    at com.queenzend.addnector.dao.impl.UserDetailedDAOImpl.getUser(UserDetailedDAOImpl.java:92)
    at com.queenzend.addnector.bo.impl.UserBOImpl.getUserByRoles(UserBOImpl.java:111)
    at com.queenzend.addnector.controller.AdminTaskController.addUSerTeam(AdminTaskController.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.queenzend.addnector.servlet.AdNectorSessionFilter.doFilter(AdNectorSessionFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole Stack trace please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441837/hibernate-throws-hibernatequeryexception-could-not-resolve-property

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that in your `UserDetailedTbl` class you are using the same name ID for the primary key id and for the foreign key from the class `UserMasterTbl`, you can see it here:

```
@Column(name="ID") // Used 'ID' here
private Integer id;


//And then 
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ID") // And Used 'ID' here
private UserMasterTbl userMasterTbl ;
```

Change the name of the JoinColumn value, maybe:

```
@JoinColumn(name="MasterUserID")
```

**Note:**

As stated in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441837/hibernate-throws-hibernatequeryexception-could-not-resolve-property), provided by [GK27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353243/gk27) in comments, make sure that you have written all the getters and setters and that they follow conventions.

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you pasted it does not have a getter and setter for `status` property in `UserMasterTbl` class. You will need to have getter and setter for all the non-transient properties of a hibernate mapped entity.

Comment: public String getStatus() {
  return status;
    }
 
  public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
  }